# Getting access to params in Grails Filter

Tags: grails, filter

WhenI try to access `params` in a Grail filter, in a utility method called in the before {} closure I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: params for class: myproject.MyFilters
```

How do I access the equivalent of the `params`  object in a filter?

Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to give a bit more information about your filter. In what part of the filter are you trying to get `params`? before, after, afterView? Is it a parsed request? Un-parsed request? The more detail you can provide in your question the better answer you will get.

Comment: I am not sure why this question has been given a close vote for "unclear what you're asking".  It isn't clear what you attempted, but what you are asking seems clear to me.

Comment: paste your code please

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this...

```
// grails-app/conf/paramsinfilter/DemoFilters.groovy
package paramsinfilter

class DemoFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                // params is available here
                println "Params in before filter: $params"
            }
            after = { Map model ->
                // params is available here
                println "Params in after filter: $params"
            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->
                // params is available here
                println "params in afterView filter: $params"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I see now that the question has been edited.  If you want to refer to the params in a utility method that you invoke from the filter you have a number of options depending on what you are really trying to do, but most likely what you will want to do is pass the params as an argument to the utility method.

```
// grails-app/conf/paramsinfilter/DemoFilters.groovy
package paramsinfilter

class DemoFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                // params is available here
                helper(params)
            }
            after = { Map model ->
                // params is available here
                helper(params)
            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->
                // params is available here
                helper(params)
            }
        }
    }

    private helper(params) {
        println "Params in helper: $params"
    }

}
```